# Calculate Javascript pixel widths for list of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list with 4 numbers.  If I divide 100 with the list's length, I get 25.  I want to set width of four elements to multiples of this number, eg. for the first, it would be 25px, for the second 50px and so on.

This is the (pseudo)code I've written so far:

```
list{1,2,3,4}
var array = list.split(',');
var width = 100 / array.length;
for (var n = 0; n < array.length; n++) {
  if(array[n]==1) {
    width = width; //here I want width as 25;
    <div style="width:"+Width +"></div>
  }
  if(array[n]==2){
    width = width+width;//here I want width as 50
    <div style="width:"+Width +"></div>
  }
  if(array[n]==3) ){
    width = width+width;//here I want width as 75
    <div style="width:"+Width +"></div>
  }
  if(array[n]==4 ){
    width = width+width;//here I want width as 100
    <div style="width:"+Width +"></div>
  }
}
```

Comment: You really need to try harder when coming up with a title for your question. Additionally, your code, as is, will not execute, and i'm not sure what all would need to be changed to make it execute because you have html seemingly at random injected into it.

Comment: The explanation of your problem seems a bit unclear. =)

Comment: First of all, you're switching between javascript and html without the correct notation. Your code has no idea what you're trying to do. Be sure to stop the HTML section before going back to javascript (note the closing quote): `</div>"}`. First edit your code along these lines and then try. You may have more success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do NOT need all those if() tests:

```
for (var n = 0; n < array.length; n++) {
   width = 25 * (n + 1);
   ...
}
```

s0

```
n = 0   -> width = 25 * (0 + 1) -> 25 * 1 -> 25
n = 1   -> width = 25 * (1 + 1) -> 25 * 2 -> 50
n = 2   -> width = 25 * (2 + 1) -> 25 * 3 -> 75
etc...
```

Comment: Thanks Marc B for u r suggestions, I was helpful

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you mix up html and javascript syntax. Html are those `<tag>` things.

First of all, I recommend you [this course](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics) or some other, just to get started with JavaScript.

To create an element in JS, you can either use [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write), which is probably much easier but may be used only *before* the document loads. You can use it like this:

```
width = 42; //or whatever
document.write('<div style="width: '+width+'px">adsf</div>');
```

Or the more difficult, but also more flexible way – to use the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/JavaScript_technologies_overview). You would do it this way:

```
var div = document.createElement('div'); //create new element
div.style.width = 42; //set its width to whatever you want
div.textContent = "some text"; //add some text into the div
someElement.appendChild(div); //insert the element into another one
```

The `someElement` here is either an element you get by calling [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) (or a similar function) or, if you want them directly inside the body, just write [`document.body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/body).

.

With respect to [@Marc_B's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32126710/1137334), the final code would look something like this:

```
var list = [1,2,3,4];
var div;
for (var n = 0; n < array.length; n++) {
  div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.width = 25*n;
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what your asking but I think you just want to times width by 2,3,4 depending on what n is.
(Go to Marc B's answer)

Edit: BTW when you declare width you by mistake (I think) use a capital W
   `var Width`
Should  be:
    `var width`

Comment: actually this would lead to `width ≈ 2ⁿ`